# Hovering on a div and displaying another one

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to display my `p` element when I hover over `footer-green`. The thing is, that I can't figure out how to display it in totally different `div`. In my css I used `.footer-green + .textAppear{}` but that seems to display it only inside the parent `div`. Any recommendations how to solve this? Note that I'm pretty much beginner with coding.

HTML :

```html
<div class="section active" id="section2">
  <div id="behind">
     <img src=" 02_Rechtwijzer-Dialoog_JvD01---web.gif" width="512" height="700" />
     <div class="footer-green"></div>
     <div class="process-green"></div>
     <div class="chat-red"></div>
     <div class="leftNavBox-red"></div>
     <div class="rightNavBox1-red"></div>
     <div class="rightNavBox2-red"></div>
     <div class="rightNavBox3-red"></div>
     <div class="dialogueBox1"></div>
     <div class="dialogueBox2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="next"> 
     <p class="textAppear">I'm invisible until you hover !</p> 
  </div>    
</div>
```

So basically I want to display .textAppear in a totally different div than #behind. Is it even possible with html/css?

Here is CSS that I have used but it is showing. TextAppear inside #behind.

CSS :

```css
.footer-green:hover + .textAppear {
   text-align: left;
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. It won't work like this. Can you put paragraph inside .process-green, or can you use Javascript?

Comment: The div classes such as .process-green or .footer-green are empty divs which I use on a picture so that when you hover on the div it changes its colour. What I would like to do is simultaneously when you hover on for example .process-green to display a .textAppear in in another div, outside the #behind. But now I can see, that I'm stupid enough to not create the new div in which I want it to appear. Im sorry, I use this for the first time so don't have the know - how.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.
You just need to specify that the `textAppear` element should be visible on ":hover".

JSbin: http://jsbin.com/guhazifope/1/edit?html,css,output

CSS:

```css
.textAppear {
  display: none
}    
.footer-green:hover + .textAppear {
  display: block
}
```

**EDIT:**

Two different JS solutions.

jQuery:

```js
$('.trigger')
 .on('mouseover',function(){
   $('.target').show();
 })
 .on('mouseout',function(){
   $('.target').hide();
 });
```

Vanilla:

```js
var trigger = document.querySelector(".trigger");
    
trigger.onmouseover = function(){
  document.querySelector(".target").style.display = 'block';
};
    
trigger.onmouseout = function(){
  document.querySelector(".target").style.display = 'none';
};
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this. It is working but I need to use this in different way. If I have a div outside the #behind, would it be possible to use this ? so that I am targeting the the argument(.textAppear) outside of the div #behind ?

Comment: If your target isn't a "sibling" to the trigger element you'll have to use js. I've updated my post with two solutions, jquery and vanilla.

Comment: @NadeemmnnMohd If your question is if you could use the adjacent sibling selector (+) in older browsers? The answer is yes [(Can i use)](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.footer-green').on("mouseover",function(){ ;
  $('.textAppear').show();
});
$('.footer-green').on("mouseout",function(){
  $('.textAppear').hide();
});
```

**See the demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/nadeemmnn2007/gm7dafh7/

Comment: require JQUERY to be included in your page .see i have included  in the demo

Comment: Thanks, it is working ! The only thing is, that all the elements I have targeted with this jquery are visible when you land on the page. You need to hover over the div first and then it will disappear. How can I make it so that when you land on the page it is not visible, only if you hover over specific div ?

Comment: can i see the example how you are loading?

Comment: See the demo : [link](http://jsfiddle.net/Chytrej/zfyd9njz/) I know the code is not all fancy but so far is working. The thing is, that when I debug the code on my pc, when I land on the page with these things, it is always showing the text first and after you hover over the specific divs, it will disappear. My guess is, that I multiplied the JQ too much and the browser is confused.

Comment: I found my way around ! I just had to state in css display:none and it is working perfectly as I want ! :)

Answer (score 0):

It also possible with the use of :has selector you can learn more about it over [here](https://css-tricks.com/the-css-has-selector/)

```css
.textAppear {
  display: none
}    
#behind:has(.footer-green:hover) + .next>.textAppear  { 
  background: green;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="section active" id="section2">
  <div id="behind">
<!--      <img src=" 02_Rechtwijzer-Dialoog_JvD01---web.gif" width="512" height="700" /> -->sss
     <div class="footer-green" style="background: red">asas</div>
     <div class="process-green"></div>
     <div class="chat-red"></div>
     <div class="leftNavBox-red"></div>
     <div class="rightNavBox1-red"></div>
     <div class="rightNavBox2-red"></div>
     <div class="rightNavBox3-red"></div>
     <div class="dialogueBox1"></div>
     <div class="dialogueBox2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="next"> 
     <p class="textAppear">I'm invisible until you hover !</p> 
  </div>    
</div>
```